Trouble accesing controller from subdirectory in MVC model PHP
I'm encountering issues with a personal project I'm developing. The problem arises when I attempt to "call" my Controller from my View in the MVC model. I receive this error message: "This page isn’t working. localhost is currently unable to handle this request." This is my project structure:
12_MVC_CRUD
├── Controller
│   └── PlataformaController.php
├── Model
│   ├── DbConnection.php
│   └── PlataformaModel.php
└── View
    ├── footer.php
    ├── header.php
    ├── Idioma
    │   └── IdiomaView.php
    ├── Pelicula
    │   ├── PeliculaAddView.php
    │   └── PeliculaView.php
    ├── Persona
    │   └── PersonaView.php
    ├── Plataforma
    │   ├── HomePlataformaView.php
    │   ├── PlataformaConfiguracionView.php
    │   ├── PlataformaView.php
    │   └── testView.php
    ├── Serie
    │   ├── SerieAddView.php
    │   ├── SerieEditView.php
    │   └── SerieView.php
    ├── Subtitulo
    │   └── SubtituloView.php
    └── testV.php

I'm trying to call "PlataformaController.php" from testView.php, which is inside the View folder > Plataforma. However, the logs are not clear to me.
When I use this command tail -n 100 php_error_log | grep testView, I get this output:
[08-May-2024 04:41:59 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/../../../Controller/PlataformaController.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php:3
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php on line 3
[08-May-2024 04:42:00 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/../../../Controller/PlataformaController.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php on line 3
[08-May-2024 04:42:00 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/../../../Controller/PlataformaController.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php:3
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php on line 3
[08-May-2024 04:42:00 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/../../../Controller/PlataformaController.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php on line 3
[08-May-2024 04:42:00 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/../../../Controller/PlataformaController.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma/testView.php:3`

This is part of my code:
<?php     require_once("../../Controller/PlataformaController.php");     $obj = new PlataformaController();  ?>

The current path is not necessarily that of the current file. If a.php includes b.php and b.php includes c.php, c.php is included from the a.php path. If you can print getcwd() from your view you can check this

This is the output /opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/View/Plataforma. I think I solved this issue by using absolute path in my view and controller.
View
require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/Controller/PlataformaController.php');
Controller
require_once('/opt/lampp/htdocs/12_MVC_CRUD/Model/PlataformaModel.php');
